# How to open access in google spreadsheet for a google api project?

Tags: api, google-api, google-sheets-api

I need a help. I have a project in google api, but i don't know how to open access in google spreadsheet for a project. So which gmail i need to open access?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing).

> Every request your application sends to the Google Sheets API needs to identify your application to Google. There are two ways to identify your application: using an [OAuth 2.0 token](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#AboutAuthorization) (which also authorizes the request) and/or using the application's [API key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey). Here's how to determine which of those options to use:
>
> - If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), then the application must provide an [OAuth 2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to.
> - If the request doesn't require authorization (such as a request for public data), then the application must provide either the API key or an OAuth 2.0 token, or both—whatever option is most convenient for you.

Here are some [examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/) and [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).